# D365 Custom JS Web Resource - ReferenceError: Web resource method does not exist: preFilterLookup

Tags: javascript, web, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

we have tried to upload a small JS web resource to filter a specific lookup field, but I keep receiving an error: **ReferenceError: Web resource method does not exist: preFilterLookup**

Here is the code that we are trying to use:

```
function preFilterLookup() {
   Xrm.Page.getControl("new_opportunitytypelookup").addPreSearch(function () {
      addLookupFilter();
   });
}

function addLookupFilter() {
   var oppScope = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_opportunityscope").getText();

   if (oppScope.getText()=="BMS Operational Outsourcing") {
      fetchXml = "<filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="cr2f5_opportunitytypeid" operator="in">
        <value uiname="aaS Offering" uitype="cr2f5_opportunitytype">{42403355-925B-EB11-A812-000D3A8C6500}</value>
        <value uiname="Operational Outsourcing" uitype="cr2f5_opportunitytype">{DF7CC32A-925B-EB11-A812-000D3A8C6500}</value>
      </condition>
    </filter>";
 Xrm.Page.getControl("new_opportunitytypelookup").addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
    }
}
```

I initially thought we even have the correct "On Change" event setup for our specific field too with the method defined [Opportunity Scope - On Change Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WmUu.png)

Comment: So how is function `preFilterLookup` wired to the form?

Comment: The `fetchXml =` statement is not correct. Is this actually the code you attempt to run?

Comment: I will take a look at the fetchXML - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have a method on form load event and define addPreSearch() for the lookup in it.
Also ***Xrm.Page*** is deprecated in Dynamics 365, so you should use **formContext** instead.
So we got this method, which should fire when the form is being loaded:

```
function onLoad(executionContext){
   var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
   formContext.getControl("new_opportunitytypelookup").addPreSearch(function () {
      addLookupFilter(executionContext);
   });
}
```

And the rest of a code:

```
function addLookupFilter(executionContext) {
   var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
   var oppScope = formContext.getAttribute("new_opportunityscope").getText();

   if (oppScope == "BMS Operational Outsourcing") {
      var fetchXml = "
        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="cr2f5_opportunitytypeid" operator="in">
            <value uiname="aaS Offering" uitype="cr2f5_opportunitytype">{42403355-925B-EB11-A812-000D3A8C6500}</value>
            <value uiname="Operational Outsourcing" uitype="cr2f5_opportunitytype">{DF7CC32A-925B-EB11-A812-000D3A8C6500}</value>
          </condition>
        </filter>";
      formContext.getControl("new_opportunitytypelookup").addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to pass the execution context when registering the onLoad event.

Comment: Wonderful - thank you so much. I am going to give this a try and will let you know how it works!